# Spring boot quartz 2.2.1 compilation error

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

This is the code i have used for saving new cron job to the postgresql database.But it is showing some compile time exceptions.I have originally migrated quartz 1.8.6 to 2.2.1 with spring boot web app.see the attachment.

[image]

```
private static final String JOBNAME = "sampleJobRunner";
    private static final String JOB_GROUPNAME = "sampleGroup";

    public void saveScheduledTime(String name) throws SchedulerException, ParseException {
        Scheduler scheduler;
        CronTrigger trigger;
        String cronExp = null;
        scheduler = this.quartzScheduler.getObject();
        trigger = (CronTrigger) scheduler.getTrigger(name, JOB_GROUPNAME);
        if (scheduler != null) {
                cronExp = "0 0 12 ? 1 MON#1 *";
            if (trigger != null) {
                rescheduleJob(scheduler, trigger.getName(), cronExp);
            } else {
                createNewCronTrigger(scheduler, cronExp, name);
            }
        }
    }
    private void rescheduleJob(Scheduler scheduler, String triggerName, String cronExp)
            throws SchedulerException, ParseException {
        CronTrigger trigger = (CronTrigger) scheduler.getTrigger(triggerName, JOB_GROUPNAME);
        trigger.setCronExpression(cronExp);
        scheduler.rescheduleJob(triggerName, JOB_GROUPNAME, trigger);
    }

    private void createNewCronTrigger(Scheduler scheduler, String cronExp, String sentType)
            throws SchedulerException, ParseException {
        CronTrigger trigger = new CronTrigger(sentType, JOB_GROUPNAME, JOBNAME, JOB_GROUPNAME, cronExp);
        scheduler.scheduleJob(trigger);
        scheduler.start();
    }
```

**Spring boot quartz configuration**

```
@Configuration
@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "quartz.enabled")
public class SchedulerConfig {
    @Bean
    public JobFactory jobFactory(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory jobFactory = new AutowiringSpringBeanJobFactory();
        jobFactory.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        return jobFactory;
    }
    @Bean
    public SchedulerFactoryBean schedulerFactoryBean(DataSource dataSource, JobFactory jobFactory,
            @Qualifier("sampleJobTrigger") Trigger sampleJobTrigger) throws IOException {
        SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBean();
        // this allows to update triggers in DB when updating settings in config
        // file:
        factory.setOverwriteExistingJobs(true);
        factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factory.setJobFactory(jobFactory);
        factory.setQuartzProperties(quartzProperties());
        // factory.setTriggers(sampleJobTrigger);
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public Properties quartzProperties() throws IOException {
        PropertiesFactoryBean propertiesFactoryBean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
        propertiesFactoryBean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("/quartz.properties"));
        propertiesFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return propertiesFactoryBean.getObject();
    }
    @Bean
    public JobDetailFactoryBean sampleJobDetail() {
        return createJobDetail(SampleJob.class);
    }
    @Bean(name = "sampleJobTrigger")
    public SimpleTriggerFactoryBean sampleJobTrigger(@Qualifier("sampleJobDetail") JobDetail jobDetail,
            @Value("${samplejob.frequency}") long frequency) {
        return createTrigger(jobDetail, frequency);
    }
    private static JobDetailFactoryBean createJobDetail(Class jobClass) {
        JobDetailFactoryBean factoryBean = new JobDetailFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobClass(jobClass);
        // job has to be durable to be stored in DB:
        factoryBean.setDurability(true);
        return factoryBean;
    }
    private static SimpleTriggerFactoryBean createTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, long pollFrequencyMs) {
        SimpleTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new SimpleTriggerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
        factoryBean.setStartDelay(0L);
        factoryBean.setRepeatInterval(pollFrequencyMs);
        factoryBean.setRepeatCount(SimpleTrigger.REPEAT_INDEFINITELY);
        // in case of misfire, ignore all missed triggers and continue :
        factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_RESCHEDULE_NEXT_WITH_REMAINING_COUNT);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't included any import statements so we can't tell what types you are referring to. The actual compilation errors would be useful too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the complilation errors in your code:

- use scheduler.getTrigger(new TriggerKey(name, JOB_GROUPNAME));
- use scheduler.rescheduleJob(new TriggerKey(name, JOB_GROUPNAME), trigger);
- cast CronTrigger to CronTriggerImpl which has the setCronExpression() method

See my sample project for Spring Boot + Quartz on github: https://github.com/davidkiss/spring-boot-quartz-demo. I updated the SchedulerConfig class with a new createCronTrigger helper method that allows to create cron triggers in Spring Boot:

```
  private static CronTriggerFactoryBean createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression) {
    CronTriggerFactoryBean factoryBean = new CronTriggerFactoryBean();
    factoryBean.setJobDetail(jobDetail);
    factoryBean.setCronExpression(cronExpression);
    factoryBean.setMisfireInstruction(SimpleTrigger.MISFIRE_INSTRUCTION_FIRE_NOW);
    return factoryBean;
  }
```

If you use Spring Boot in your project, I believe using the SchedulerConfig class is a cleaner way of configuring quartz jobs in Spring Boot then calling the saveScheduledTime() method.

In order to create any cron triggers, I'd add additional methods in the SchedulerConfig class to create the appropriate trigger beans similar to sampleJobTrigger.

Comment: thanks for your quick response...According to your example on github i need to call createCronTrigger(JobDetail jobDetail, String cronExpression). But what is the job detail should i pass.Below is my JobDetails
JobDetail job = JobBuilder.newJob(SampleJob.class)
    .withIdentity(name, "group1").build();

Comment: Please add you github project with saving new cron trigger

Comment: See the SchedulerConfig.sampleJobDetail() method as a sample on how to create a JobDetail bean, but you could use the JobBuilder code in your comment, too

Comment: what group name shoul i use accourding to your example.

Comment: JobDetailFactoryBean jobDetailFactoryBean =  SchedulerConfig.createJobDetail(SampleJob.class,name);
  JobDetail jobDetail = jobDetailFactoryBean.getObject();
  CronTriggerFactoryBean cronTriggerFactoryBean = SchedulerConfig.createCronTrigger(jobDetail, "0/5 * * * * ?");
  Trigger trigger = cronTriggerFactoryBean.getObject();
  Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
  scheduler.start();
  scheduler.scheduleJob(jobDetail, trigger);
i used this code for scheduling the job.But it is showing jobdetail cannot be null exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is purely a result of the migration from Quartz 1.8.6 to 2.2.1. Quartz did some code changes with 2.x version. You need to make changes in your application to respect that. Have a look at this: http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/migration-guide.html

Comment: the link is dead